# Unable to scroll smoothly listView of Images in android 4.1

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a listView of images to scroll images, the listView scrolls smoothly on 2.3 but not on phones with OS 4.0+ . All the images are being fetched from R.drawable Please find my code attached

**image_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#A4A4A4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the type of collection you have used.?

Comment: List<Record> arrayList=new ArrayList<Record>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SparseArray<E>` for getting the better performance of drawable images list.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your listview :

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

this removes flickering while scrolling list...